# How to pass a token which my api uses as header in appscript?

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets, sourceforge-appscript

So i am getting trouble in passing the token which my api uses as header, I tried in postman api works fine, Its an internal api.

Whereas when it come to code which is present in appscript it works fine with open apis but when I try to use my own internal api it throws error as :

Exception: Request failed for https://api.rupeek.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"message":"Bad authentication"}

sharing the appscript code below :
[tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name)

```
 function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Rupeek Menu')
      .addItem('Get Ref ID','displayrefid')
      .addToUi();
}
 

// function to call Rupeek API
function callrpkAPI(rpk) {
  
  // Call the Rupeek api

  var url = 'api url';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, token);
  var token = {
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "MY JWT token passing here ",
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "body": "phone",
};

  
  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json);
  
}
 
 
function displayrefid() {
  
  // pick up the search term from the Google Sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var ref = sheet.getRange(4,2).getValue();
  
  var id = callrpkAPI(ref);
  
  var results = id["results"];
  
  var output = []
  // clear any previous content
  sheet.getRange(15,1).clearContent();
  
  // paste in the values
  sheet.getRange(15,1).setValues(sortedOutput);
  
}
```

Please let me know if you guys get the solution for this stuck in this for last 2 days.

So i am getting trouble in passing the token which my api uses as header, I tried in postman api works fine, Its an internal api.

Whereas when it come to code which is present in appscript it works fine with open apis but when I try to use my own internal api it throws error as :

Exception: Request failed for https://api.rupeek.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"message":"Bad authentication"}

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the API you want to use, the request of UrlFechApp has no property of `body`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) Also, unfortunately, I cannot know your request body. If you want to use the request body, it is required to modify `body` to `payload`. By the way, if you want to use the request body, it is required to use the POST method. But, in your script, the GET method is used. Unfortunately, I cannot know your API. So, I cannot propose the modified script. I apologize for this.

Comment: I am using an internal api 
https://api.rupeek.com/pay/api/search/v3/getcustomerloans?phone=7259339954
This uses header in header there is present authorization and content type 
without token api does not give response. 

@tanike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the specification of the API you want to use.